# Oracle SQL other database use in update or if

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

i use ORACLE SQL and i want to Update a table with conditions. One Condition is that in a other database the table is the value null. But i get the error '**Table, view or sequence reference 'Db2table.MERGE_UNIT_ID' not valid in this context.**' For this I create a new table with the column of the table of DB2 and i want to use it to compare it.

```
create table db2table as (select r.merge_einheit_id from be_einheit be join DB2.r_be_einheit r on be.id = r.id)
 
begin
    if db2table.merge_einheit_id is null
       then Update be_einheit set be_einheit.CHDATE=sysdate  
          where be_einheit.merge_einheit_id is not null 
          and be_einheit.id= be_container.einheit_id;
    end if;
end;
```

my second approch is that i add it to the WHERE with an AND, but then i get the Error '**"DB2"."MERGE_EINHEIT_ID":invalid identifier**'.
Anyone have any idea what this is or how i can get adas problem solved?

````
begin
 Update be_einheit set be_einheit.CHDATE=sysdate  
     where be_einheit.merge_einheit_id is not null 
     and be_einheit.id= be_container.einheit_id
     and db2table.merge_einheit_id is null;
end;```
````

Comment: for me it sounds like you are trying to operate with tables located in the different databases or even servers. If so I guess you need to have a look on Oracle db-link

Comment: Thanks i look at it. But i can make a 'select * from db2table' and this works. Do I not need oracle db-link for this?

Comment: If so then please take a look on the syntax.Your second query looks extremely suspicious. It needs at least a join between be_einheit and db2table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a table won't help much *in long term* because that table is a *static* object; if anything changes in tables you used in CTAS, `db2table` won't know anything about it.

If you successfully created `db2table`, then - according to join condition (join **DB2.**r_be_einheit on) - you aren't actually talking about other **database** - it is just another **schema** in the same database. Furthermore, it means that owner (`db2`) granted (at least) `select` privilege on `r_be_einheit` to you. That's OK.

To me, it looks as if something like this might do:

```
update be_einheit be set
  be.einheit.chdate = sysdate
  where exists (select null 
                from db2.r_be_einheit r
                where r.id = be.id
                  and r.merge_einheit_id is null
               )
    and exists (select null
                from be_container bc
                where bc.einheit_id = be.id
               )
    and be.merge_einheit_id is not null;
```